# Can't assign to Int from Date extension's function

Tags: ios, swift

I need to get how many days there are from two dates, so I've used this code I've found online

```
extension Date {

    func years(_ sinceDate: Date) -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: sinceDate, to: self).year
    }

    func months(_ sinceDate: Date) -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: sinceDate, to: self).month
    }

    func days(_ sinceDate: Date) -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: sinceDate, to: self).day
    }

    func hours(_ sinceDate: Date) -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: sinceDate, to: self).hour
    }

    func minutes(_ sinceDate: Date) -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: sinceDate, to: self).minute
    }

    func seconds(_ sinceDate: Date) -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: sinceDate, to: self).second
    }  
}
```

which is an extension of the Date class.

I'm facing a problem when using those functions, I have this function

```
func countDays() {
        if let daysLeft = Date.days(targetDate) {
            self.daysLeft = daysLeft
        }
    }
```

but Xcode tells me that

*Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '(Date) -> Int?'*

So, then I tried this function

```
func countDays() {
        let daysLeft = Date.days(targetDate)
        self.daysLeft = daysLeft
    }
```

Still Xcode tells me that

*Cannot assign value of type '(Date) -> Int?' to type 'Int'*

I've tried building the project a few times because I thought it could be an error but the issue remains.

Can anyone point out what could be the issue here? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've already tried to force unwrap the returned values like this

```
func years(_ sinceDate: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: sinceDate, to: self).year!
    }
```

Still Xcode tells me the same thing
*Cannot assign value of type '(Date) -> Int' to type 'Int'*

Comment: Not related to your question but Why don't you simply force unwrap the result? Every date has the year component. It will never fail.

Comment: `func years(_ sinceDate: Date) -> Int {`
       `return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: sinceDate, to: self).year!`
   `}`

Comment: The problem still remain, I've tried all those kind of edit but Xcode still gives me *Cannot assign value of type '(Date) -> Int' to type 'Int'*

Comment: changing the return property would need to remove the if keyword. please update your question with your actual code. Btw you should add a better descriptive parameter name. something like `func years(since date: Date) -> Int {`

Comment: The problem here is that Xcode sees that return value as `(Date) -> Int` no matter how I write those functions. I'm going to edit OP to show that

Comment: `let years = Date().years(since: targetDate)`

Comment: That Date() did the trick, why can't I just write Date.method as I do sometimes?

Comment: It is not a static method. You need a date instance

Comment: Even if I declare it static it doesn't work. How would you edit one of my function in a static function? Because just writing `static` in front of it will make Xcode complain again as I wrote in the comment down below

Comment: try `extension Date {
    static func days(since date: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date, to: Date()).day!
    }
}
Date.days(since: targetDate)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191621/discussion-between-mattia-righetti-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: Note that I am not recommending to declare your method as static in this case. I would keep it as an instance method. I would actually use a computed property `extension Date {
    var daysSinceNow: Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: self).day!
    }
}
Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: -2), to: Date())!.daysSinceNow // -2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function on the `Date` type. However, the function is not `static`. You have to create a date instance and call the function on that:

```
let now = Date()
if let daysLeft = now.days(targetDate) {
   self.daysLeft = daysLeft
}
```

Comment: Previously I've tried to declare the extension' funcs as static but it gave me this error: *Type of expression is ambiguous without more context* in the extension file. Is there a cleaner way to write this function so that I'll just need to write Date.days(...)?

Comment: @MattiaRighetti You are calculating the difference between two dates. Either you have to pass both as parameters or `self` is one of them. You can use a `static` function only if you pass both as parameters.

Comment: That's right, calling Date() makes the issue go away, but how do I need to declare the function to be able to call Date.days(tagetDate) without () after Date?
Writing `static` in front of the func makes Xcode complain

Comment: @MattiaRighetti I repeat, if you want to call `Date.days(...)` then you two  parameters, e.g. `static func days(since: Date, target: Date)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use standard functionality from the Calendar class

```
let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
```

example

```
let date1 = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -800000)
print(date1)
let date2 = Date()
print(date2)

let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
if let count = days.day {
    print(count)
}
```

Yields

> 2019-04-01 13:24:14 +0000
>   2019-04-10 19:37:34 +0000
>   9

Comment: I just wanted to have cleaner and have less redundant code, that's why I wrote that extension.